# Fetching data from the Api and using hooks in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, use-effect

I have a list of countries that is fetched from an API and then stored in the browser's local storage.

[image]

I need to fetch the states for the selected country from an API and then fetch the cities against each state of the selected country from the API as well. The data would then look something like this:

```
[
   {
      "country":"USA",
      "states":[
         {
            "state":"Alabama",
            "cities":[
               {
                  "city":"Alexander City",
                  "city":"Andalusia"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "state":"Alaska",
            "cities":[
               {
                  "city":"Anchorage"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "country":"Algeria"
   },
   {
      "country":"Andorra"
   }
]
```

**Note:** There will be one or more states for each country and likewise, one or more cities against each state.

Lastly, I need to keep updating the data inside the local storage.

So that means a country is selected by the user. Before going towards the API to fetch its state(s) and cities, I first need to check the local storage data list. If the related states/cities of the selected country are there, then I have to render it right away. Otherwise, I fetch the data from the API, display the data and update the local storage. If the same country is selected again, I would not need to call the API as the data from the last call has already been used to update the data list inside the local storage.

In order to display the data, I am using a table (parent component) where the list of countries is displayed. Each row contains one country. After clicking on the row, I am seeking to show the states of the country and cities against each state in another table (child component).

Here is how it looks when a country is clicked in the table:

[image]

Code of the child table component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import httpService from "../services/httpService";

const ExpandComponent = ({ countries, data: { country: selectedCountry } }) => {
  const country = countries.find((m) => m.country === selectedCountry);
  const [countryStates, setCountryStates] = useState(country.states || []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!country.states) {
      fetchStatesFromApi();
    }
  }, []);

  const fetchStatesFromApi = () => {
    httpService
      .get(
        `http://localhost/states?country=${selectedCountry}`
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        //updating data in local storage
        const { data } = response.data;
        updateStorage(data);
        //update global country object
        country.states = data;
        //update the state
        setCountryStates(data);
        //fetch cities for each state
        fetchCitiesFromApi(data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          updateStorage([]);
        }
      });
  };

  const fetchCitiesFromApi = (states) => {
    states.forEach((m) => {
      const stateName = m.state;
      httpService
        .get(
          `http://localhost/cities?state=${stateName}&country=${selectedCountry}`
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          const { data } = response.data;
          //adding cities to the state
          return addCitiesToState(data, stateName);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          if (error.response.status === 400) {
            //adding empty cities to the state
            return addCitiesToState([], stateName);
          }
        })
        .then((states) => {
          //Updating localstorage
          updateStorage(states);
          //update global country object
          country.states = states;
          //Updating state of the component
          setCountryStates(states);
        });
    });
  };

  function addCitiesToState(cities, stateName) {
    return country.states.map((p) =>
      p.state === stateName
        ? {
            ...p,
            cities: cities,
          }
        : p
    );
  }

  function updateStorage(states) {
    const cntrs = countries.map((p) =>
      p.country === selectedCountry
        ? {
            ...p,
            states: states,
          }
        : p
    );
    localStorage.setItem("countriesData", JSON.stringify(cntrs));
  }

  if (!countryStates?.length) {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="text-danger">No states available.</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-secondary table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Cities</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {countryStates.map((m, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{m.state}</td>
              <td>
                {m?.cities?.length ? (
                  m.cities.map((m) => m.city).join(", ")
                ) : (
                  <span className="text-danger">No cities available.</span>
                )}
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ExpandComponent;
```

**Note:** The `httpService` uses axios.

I want to do this the "react way". Make use of the state variable properly, get rid of the global variable `country` and anything that is unnecessary in this code. For now, it feels like a linear program where I am calling one function after the other.

If I remove the global variable `country` I run into issues because `setCountryStates` does not immediately update the state even though the promise of `httpService.get` is resolved inside the `.then()` block. I have tried a lot of things but unfortunately, only the above code achieves the result I want and I know this isn't the right way to go about the business in react.js.

P.S. I am new to react.js and just have a basic understanding of JS.

Comment: Just to summarize your question, you get the countries at the start and when they select one, you get it's counties. Then when they select a county, you get it's cities. And you want to cache them using the localstorage so you don't have to make the same request twice?

Comment: @Invizi I got the list of countries at the start, stored it in local storage and am showing it in the parent component. When they select a country from the table in the parent component, I need to get its states and cities. Yes, I want to cache the data of states and cities just like I have done it with countries already.